# Sticky Header in recylerview + Pull to refresh + Load more

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sticky

i want to implement sticky header like instagram i am using [this](https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview) library.

i am getting data when data is load.but when i do pull to refresh or load more header height will increase as shown in image. [image: i am getting this data when item is loaded.][image: when i do pull to refresh header height will be increased as show in image.]

Comment: Does your header height contains _wrap_content_

Comment: @Piyush no.its match_parent

Comment: Set it to _wrap_content_

Comment: yes i have set.but its not work.